# Twillio sendDigits for CallerID (outbound calls)

Tags: twilio

After searching I could find a `TWIML noun 'sendDigits'` which sends digits to the destination number like following:

```
<Dial record="true" callerId="415-123-1111">
      <Number sendDigits="wwww1928">
        415-123-4567
      </Number>
</Dial>
```

What I need is to `send digits to the 'CallerId'` (we need to use callerId's which are already in extension system locally). I could find nothing in TWIML References for this.

Can anybody please tell me a work around to send Digits for 'CallerID'.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean send digits to the Caller ID?

Comment: @ajtrichards I want same what Carter Rabsa explained in his answer below.. That was what i wanted. Suggest any thing better if you can.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Twilio employee here. I think I understand what you're trying to do: you want to connect person A (phone number + extension) to person B (phone number + extension). Is this correct?

If so, you're half way there, you've essentially coded the 2nd half of the call (to person B). But you need to use the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post) to initiate a call to Person A. The API call takes 3 parameters:

- To - the phone number for person A
- From - the caller ID you want person A to see when their phone rings (usually a Twilio #)
- URL - the URL to your TwiML

The TwiML you send to Twilio should look something like this:

```
<Play digits="12345"/>
<!-- at this point you've successfully connected to Person A -->
<Dial record="true" callerId="TWILIO NUMBER HERE">
  <Number sendDigits="wwww1928">
    415-123-4567
  </Number>
</Dial>
<!-- at this point you've successfully connected to Person B -->
```

The key thing to remember is that connecting a call between two people is a 2-step process: first use the REST API to establish a live call to the 1st person and then use TwiML and  to establish a live call to the 2nd person. Then Twilio bridges them together.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer! You actually got my point i wanted same... I am doing on your suggested solution.. Hope it will help...

Comment: By using your suggested steps.. both A and B phones get call(ring) at the same time. While we were expecting that B would be connected/ring after A would accept the call... Any ideas???

Comment: Carter Rabasa, Thanks again for your solution that really worked to connect both A and B in the given scenario! But the issue is by using this solution both A and B get connected at the same time.. While the default behavior for callerId's is a little different. In default A get connected and when A accept call then B get connected... Any help regarding this would be appreciated.. Thank's